# How to solve invocation of init method failed: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am trying JBOSS Eap 6.4 to 7.2 migration.

My project runs fine on jboss eap 6 server. but when I try to deploy it on jboss eap 7.2 server I get following error.

Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DUMMY' defined in ServletContext resource: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Becuase your new container ships with a newer XML library API which isn't implemented by the actual library implementation shipped with your application. Either fix classloading or don't include the library (jaxb or the likes) inside your application.

Comment: Hi @M. Deinum, I didn't understood your comment, can you elaborate more?

Comment: You are upgrading an app server. That app server ships with libraries and API's. You are using that API through dependencies in your application (probably some XML processing library). The API in the app-server is newer then the API supported by your actual library, leading to issues as the server expects a certain API version.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But how do I implement this? what configurations I need to make this work?

Comment: That I already answered in my first comment. Either remove the library from your application and use the one from the app-server instead. Or fix classloading (how to do that is explained in the documentation of your container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this statement in VM Arguments solved my issue:

```
Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

I took reference from here,

http://developerblogging.blogspot.com/2013/04/javalangabstractmethoderror.html

posting the answer, just so if anyone facing the same issue can refer.